# Prestashop api - creating order history doesn't send e-mail

Tags: web-services, api, prestashop

I'm trying to add order history (and change order_state with that) by using prestashop api:

```
$xml = $this->api->get(array('url' => $url . '/api/order_histories?schema=blank'));
$xml->order_history->id_order_state = 4;
$xml->order_history->id_order = $order_id;
unset( $xml->order_history->id );
unset( $xml->order_history->date_add );
$xml = $this->api->add(array(
  'resource' => 'order_histories',
  'postXml' => $xml->asXML()
));
```

It works just fine (order_state is changed) but presta doesn't sending any notification to buyer.

Answer (score 3):

Set this line:

```
'resource' => 'order_histories',
```

To this:

```
'resource' => 'order_histories?sendemail=1',
```

Comment: Thanks. For anybody else, who after adding sendemail=1 is getting errors from the API, check your mail server. I had PrestaShop on localhost without mail server, so I had to turn off e-mails in Advanced Parameters > E-mail > Never send emails (may be useful for testing purposes).